# Papervision: MovieMaterial on a Collada object

Tags: flash, video, 3d, papervision3d, collada

Is it possible to put a MovieMaterial on an imported Collada object in Papervision? I can't find anything on the matter on the internet and anything I try on my own is in vain...

Thank you

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've already seen several times a MovieMaterial applied on a Collada object on some blogs.

Can't remember right now where exactly but If I find something, I'll let you know.

Also, if you could post some code , one might tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DisplayObject3D's have a "replaceMaterialByName(material:MaterialObject3D, name:String):void" method which will allow you to do that. Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried that before but it didn't work at once so I just left it.
After some debugging it now works great. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

I think DisplayObject3D's also allow you to just say

```
DisplayObject3D.material = new MovieMaterial(new arbitraryMovieClip(), false, true);
```

I typed that without looking at anything so it may have a typo in it,
I just did it to a sphere yesterday